# Proper use of NDSolve in the context of the reduced 3 body problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, physics, nonlinear

I am currently trying to solve the reduced three body problem in *Mathematica*. I have the equations of motion

$\ddot{x}-2\dot{y}=-\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial x } $

$\ddot{y}+2\dot{x}=-\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial y } $

$\Omega=-\frac{1}{2}\mu r_1^2-\frac{1}{2}(1-\mu)r_2^2-\frac{\mu}{r_1}-\frac{1-\mu}{r_2}$

Where $r_{1,2}$ are the distances between the small body and the two massive bodies , and $\mu$ is such that the ratio of the masses is $\mu:1-\mu$. I have shown that $J=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}\dot{y}^2+\Omega(x,y)$ is conserved, by differentiating wrt time. Then to obtain the motion I wrote the code below, but I cannot seem to get $J$ to be conserved. Does anyone have a clue why?

Plotting $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ gives some discontinuous derivatives at $t=6s$ which is when there is the first major change in the value of $J$. I tried forcing `NDSolve` to use Runge-Kutta but that didn't help, forcing it to use Euler gave nonsense (outward spiralling circular orbit, as if there were no gravity)

```
r1[x_, y_, u_] := Sqrt[ (x + 1 - u)^2 + y^2]

u = 1/2

r2[x_, y_, u_] := Sqrt[(x - u)^2 + y^2]

Om[x_, y_, u_] := -1/2*u*r1[x, y, u]^2 - 1/2*(1 - u)*r2[x, y, u]^2 - 
  u/r1[x, y, u] - (1 - u)/r2[x, y, u]

sol = NDSolve[ {x''[t] - 2 y'[t] == -D[Om[x[t], y[t], u], x[t]], 
   y''[t] + 2 x'[t] == -D[Om[x[t], y[t], u], y[t]], x[0] == y[0] == 0,
    x'[0] == y'[0] == 0.5}, {x, y}, {t, 100} ]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
J[t_] := 1/2*dX[t]^2 + 1/2*dY[t]^2 + Om[X[t], Y[t], u]

pX[t_] := x[t] /. sol
X[t_] := pX[t][[1]]

pdX[t_] := x'[t] /. sol
dX[t_] := pdX[t][[1]]

pY[t_] := y[t] /. sol
Y[t_] := pY[t][[1]]

pdY[t_] := y'[t] /. sol
dY[t_] := pdY[t][[1]]

(* dX[t] gives derivative of x[t], X[t] gives x[t]. We introduce X 
and Y to obtain reals, not one element lists, which correspond, e.g., 
to x[t]/.sol  *)

Plot[Evaluate[J[t]], {t, 1, 30}]
```

I have also tried modifying `PrecisionGoal` in `NDSolve` but this leads to straight line trajectories (no gravity again) for `PrecisionGoal` greater than about `20`.

One way I am trying to verify the accuracy of the simulation is by generating the Moulton orbits described in this paper: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?db_key=AST&bibcode=1967AJ.....72..373S. This has been achieved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is, in fact, `WorkingPrecison`.  Whenever `r1` or `r2` approach zero, high accuracy is needed for the computation.  Try

```
sol = NDSolve[ {x''[t] - 2 y'[t] == -D[Om[x[t], y[t], u], x[t]], 
    y''[t] + 2 x'[t] == -D[Om[x[t], y[t], u], y[t]], x[0] == y[0] == 0,
    x'[0] == y'[0] == 1/2}, {x, y, x', y'}, {t, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 75, 
    MaxSteps -> 500000, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
J[t_] = ((x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)/2 + Om[x[t], y[t], u]);
Plot[J[t]/.sol, {t, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, J}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

[image]

`WorkingPrecision -> 75` seems to be large enough; `30` definitely is not.

Answer (score 7):

Another thing to try is the `Projection` method of `NDSolve`:

```
u = 1/2;
r1[x_, y_, u_] = Sqrt[(x + 1 - u)^2 + y^2];
r2[x_, y_, u_] = Sqrt[(x - u)^2 + y^2];
Om[x_, y_, u_] = -1/2*u*r1[x, y, u]^2 - 1/2*(1 - u)*r2[x, y, u]^2 - 
   u/r1[x, y, u] - (1 - u)/r2[x, y, u];
J[t_] = 1/2*x'[t]^2 + 1/2*y'[t]^2 + Om[x[t], y[t], u];    

sol2 = NDSolve[{x''[t] - 2 y'[t] == -D[Om[x[t], y[t], u], x[t]], 
       y''[t] + 2 x'[t] == -D[Om[x[t], y[t], u], y[t]], x[0] == y[0] == 0,
        x'[0] == y'[0] == 1/2}, {x, y}, {t, 100}, MaxSteps -> 500000, 
      Method -> {"Projection", Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
        "Invariants" -> J[t]}]
```

[image]

This gives a result in under a second compared to a minute for bbgodfrey's solution, but still has rather large oscillations in the invariant of the interpolating functions. `InvariantErrorPlot` shows these as smaller, but I had to play with the syntax to get that to work (define extra variables `xd`,`yd` in the `NDSolve`).

Following the discussions in the comment section, note that this system is chaotic, and this method begins to visually diverge with the solution with `WorkingPrecision -> 75` at around $t=20$:

[image]

This can be fixed by increasing the `WorkingPrecision` with the `Projection` method, but that takes more computational time. It doesn't require as high WP to get the same results to $t=100$ though, WP=40 instead of WP=75, which takes about a third of the computational time.

Note that changing the initial conditions in the WP=75 solution by $10^{-15}$, the solutions diverge around $t=90$, due to the chaotic nature of the system.

Comment: Nice approach.  However, I noticed that your plot differed substantially from mine, so I investigated.  With `WorkingPrecision  ->  75` your plot becomes essentially the same as mine.  The point, I believe, is that the "Projection" method does conserve the invariant well, but doing so does not necessarily assure an accurate overall solution.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that they were different. They begin to diverge at about $t=20$, and once they do diverge the chaotic nature of the system means they are very different.

Comment: So it depends on what the use-case of the simulation is as to whether the accuracy of one particular simulation is important.

Comment: But, why not increase `WorkingPrecision ` until the answer stops changing?

Comment: Because it takes 100 times longer. If you change the initial conditions by $10^-15$ with your solution with `WorkingPrecision->75`, the solutions diverge at $t=90$. If the goal is determining a spacecraft launch then yes, you want as accurate as possible. If the goal is just to plot a plausible orbit then the fast answer is good.